# How to create different object of different class based on different parameter?

Tags: c#, object, polymorphism

Assuming I have a Apple class that extend from Fruit Class

and I have Orange class that extend from Fruit class too

both class have two different constructor

Apple have Apple(size, colour, taste, weight);
Orange have Orange(size, radius, diameter);

Each object got their own unique method I have to call

How do I create different instances, JUST BY CREATING the FRUIT CLASS? base on different parameters? like

```
Fruit a = new Fruit(int size, int colour, String taste, int weight); To create apple
Fruit a = new Fruit(int size, int radius, int diameter); To create orange
```

How do I do it? Please help

UPDATE:

I understand I must use factory, but I wasn't train to do it, how do I use Factory in C# to achieve the above

Because my boss say he only want the user to enter the parameter in to the fruit class without caring the name of the fruit. He told me something call factory in java, how do I do it?

Comment: In short: you don't. The constructors are fruit-type-specific, so why would you try and force both of their constructors in the baseclass fruit? If you _know_ you're creating an Apple (because you're calling the Apple-specific constructor), why not new an Apple() in stead of Fruit()?

You might want to take a look at a Factory, where you could implement CreateFruit with several overloads to return specific fruits based on the signature.

Comment: `Each object got their own unique method` - yet your question is tagged [polymorphism] - I think you need to go look up that word. Also, I think you need to seek some clarification from your boss. What he's asked you makes zero sense.

Comment: What he meant is he want the Fruit object to automatically categories the object into Apple or Orange without declaring the apple or orange, base on the parameter enter by the user

Comment: `Fruit` is just a base class (it should, probably/logically be abstract). Asking `Fruit` to `automatically categories the object into Apple or Orange ` makes no sense. By "Boss" do you mean "teacher"? This is a school assignment, right? (I say that because in the  world of programming we rarely actually model "Fruit" in code :)

Comment: I am just seeking help, it is okay if you don't know about factory

Comment: @user2399158: Your boss is not understanding how this should work. The whole point of making derived classes is so that you can use the derived classes. It is impossible to make an object of type `Fruit` and then cast it to any of its derived classes. If he wants an automated decision which fruit it is to be created, based on the given parameters, you should create a method that decides which class constructor your should use based on the given parameters. Using only the base class constructor is nonsensical and completely missing the point of polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the constructors from the derived classes:

```
Fruit a = new Apple(size, colour, taste, weight);
```

Based on your updated question, if you use a factory, your factory will be returning the Fruit type so I don't see much benefit over simply using constructor overloading:

```
public class Fruit
{
     public Fruit(int size, int colour, string taste, int weight) { }
     public Fruit(int size, int radius, int diameter) { }
}
```

Comment: I cannot do that, I have to call from Fruit class

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your updated question. Each different constructor could, for example, set an enum property on the Fruit class to signify if it's an apple, orange etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public static Fruit CreateFruit(string v1, string v2)
    {
        return new Apple(v1, v2);
    }

    public static Fruit CreateFruit(string v1, int v2, int v3)
    {
        return new Orange(v1, v2, v3);
    }
}

public class Apple : Fruit
{
    string var1 { get; set; }
    string var2 { get; set; }

    public Apple(string v1, string v2)
    {
        this.var1 = v1;
        this.var2 = v2;
    }
}


public class Orange : Fruit
{
    string var1 { get; set; }
    int var2 { get; set; }
    int var3 { get; set; }

    public Orange(string v1, int v2, int v3)
    {
        this.var1 = v1;
        this.var2 = v2;
        this.var3 = v3;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean to make your factory methods static? With them instance this would be *weird* - you'd need an instance of `Fruit` to call them.

Comment: you're right. I've changed method CreateFruit to static

Comment: Technically perfectly fine, but it's basically wrapping a factory in a base class for the sole reason of conforming to a seemingly nonsensical rule. Not your fault of course, you answered the question directly :)